# verilog old values problems

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

I am almost finished implementing a 5-stage-pipeline Mips Cpu on FPGA board(Spartan 3E starter kit). But one Module has a critical problem.

That problem is when mMdule take Data from input signal, Module take **old values**.
That Module is register which is the most important part of CPU.

here is Screenshot(Isim):
[screenshot http://cfile8.uf.tistory.com/original/2441AB3351B74AD217FE01](http://cfile8.uf.tistory.com/original/2441AB3351B74AD217FE01)

Gray arrow is what I design(What I want).

But Module work as red arrow.

Module define

```
(When reg_write is true) and (Clk is true-not show in screenshot)
register[write_reg]=write_data;
```

I have my own FPGA board(Spartan 3E starter kit)

I implement only this module on board. I made `signal(Clk, signal. write_reg, write_data)` with onboard sw0~4. (even though clk)

and then it working!

no problem.

but when use this Module in Whole CPU design.

Module Occur old values problem.

Here is the whole source

```
module reg1(Reset, Clk, read_reg1, read_reg2, write_reg, write_data, reg_write, read_data1, read_data2
);

 input Reset;
 input Clk;
 input reg_write;
input [4:0] read_reg1, read_reg2, write_reg; 
 input [31:0] write_data;    
 output [31:0] read_data1;
 output [31:0] read_data2;

 reg [31:0] register [11:0];     
 reg [31:0] read_data1_reg;
reg [31:0] read_data2_reg;
 wire [31:0] read_data1=read_data1_reg;
 wire [31:0] read_data2=read_data2_reg;

always @(reg_write or Reset or read_reg1 or read_reg2)
 begin
 if(reg_write == 1'b0 )
  begin
    case(read_reg1)
    5'b00000: read_data1_reg=register[0];
    5'b00001: read_data1_reg=register[1];
    5'b00010: read_data1_reg=register[2];
    5'b00011: read_data1_reg=register[3];
    5'b00100: read_data1_reg=register[4];
    5'b00101: read_data1_reg=register[5];
    5'b00110: read_data1_reg=register[6];
    5'b00111: read_data1_reg=register[7];
    5'b01000: read_data1_reg=register[8];
    5'b01001: read_data1_reg=register[9];
    5'b01010: read_data1_reg=register[10];
    5'b01011: read_data1_reg=register[11];
    default: read_data1_reg=32'h00000000;
    endcase

    case(read_reg2)
    5'b00000: read_data2_reg=register[0];
    5'b00001: read_data2_reg=register[1];
    5'b00010: read_data2_reg=register[2];
    5'b00011: read_data2_reg=register[3];
    5'b00100: read_data2_reg=register[4];
    5'b00101: read_data2_reg=register[5];
    5'b00110: read_data2_reg=register[6];
    5'b00111: read_data2_reg=register[7];
    5'b01000: read_data2_reg=register[8];
    5'b01001: read_data2_reg=register[9];
    5'b01010: read_data2_reg=register[10];
    5'b01011: read_data2_reg=register[11];
    default: read_data2_reg=32'h00000000;

    endcase
  end
 else
 begin
    if(Clk==1'b1)
        case(write_reg)
        5'b00000: register[0] = write_data;
        5'b00001: register[1] = write_data;
        5'b00010: register[2] = write_data;
        5'b00011: register[3] = write_data;
        5'b00100: register[4] = write_data;
        5'b00101: register[5] = write_data;
        5'b00110: register[6] = write_data;
        5'b00111: register[7] = write_data;
        5'b01000: register[8] = write_data;
        5'b01001: register[9] = write_data;
        5'b01010: register[10] = write_data;
        5'b01011: register[11] = write_data;
        default: register[0] = register[0];
        endcase
else
    begin
    //read_data1_reg = register[read_reg1];
    //read_data2_reg = register[read_reg2];
    case(read_reg1)
    5'b00000: read_data1_reg=register[0];
    5'b00001: read_data1_reg=register[1];
    5'b00010: read_data1_reg=register[2];
    5'b00011: read_data1_reg=register[3];
    5'b00100: read_data1_reg=register[4];
    5'b00101: read_data1_reg=register[5];
    5'b00110: read_data1_reg=register[6];
    5'b00111: read_data1_reg=register[7];
    5'b01000: read_data1_reg=register[8];
    5'b01001: read_data1_reg=register[9];
    5'b01010: read_data1_reg=register[10];
    5'b01011: read_data1_reg=register[11];
    default: read_data1_reg=32'h00000000;
    endcase

    case(read_reg2)
    5'b00000: read_data2_reg=register[0];
    5'b00001: read_data2_reg=register[1];
    5'b00010: read_data2_reg=register[2];
    5'b00011: read_data2_reg=register[3];
    5'b00100: read_data2_reg=register[4];
    5'b00101: read_data2_reg=register[5];
    5'b00110: read_data2_reg=register[6];
    5'b00111: read_data2_reg=register[7];
    5'b01000: read_data2_reg=register[8];
    5'b01001: read_data2_reg=register[9];
    5'b01010: read_data2_reg=register[10];
    5'b01011: read_data2_reg=register[11];
    default: read_data2_reg=32'h00000000;

    endcase
    end

 end


  if(Reset)
     begin
     register[0] = 32'h00000000;
     register[1] = 32'h00000000;
     register[2] = 32'h00000000;
     register[3] = 32'h00000000;
     register[4] = 32'h00000000;
     register[5] = 32'h00000000;
     register[6] = 32'h00000000;
     register[7] = 32'h00000000;
     register[8] = 32'h00000000;
     register[9] = 32'h00000000;
     register[10] = 32'h00000000;
     register[11] = 32'b00000000000000000000000110010000;


     case(read_reg1)
    5'b00000: read_data1_reg=register[0];
    5'b00001: read_data1_reg=register[1];
    5'b00010: read_data1_reg=register[2];
    5'b00011: read_data1_reg=register[3];
    5'b00100: read_data1_reg=register[4];
    5'b00101: read_data1_reg=register[5];
    5'b00110: read_data1_reg=register[6];
    5'b00111: read_data1_reg=register[7];
    5'b01000: read_data1_reg=register[8];
    5'b01001: read_data1_reg=register[9];
    5'b01010: read_data1_reg=register[10];
    5'b01011: read_data1_reg=register[11];
    default: read_data1_reg=32'h00000000;
    endcase

    case(read_reg2)
    5'b00000: read_data2_reg=register[0];
    5'b00001: read_data2_reg=register[1];
    5'b00010: read_data2_reg=register[2];
    5'b00011: read_data2_reg=register[3];
    5'b00100: read_data2_reg=register[4];
    5'b00101: read_data2_reg=register[5];
    5'b00110: read_data2_reg=register[6];
    5'b00111: read_data2_reg=register[7];
    5'b01000: read_data2_reg=register[8];
    5'b01001: read_data2_reg=register[9];
    5'b01010: read_data2_reg=register[10];
    5'b01011: read_data2_reg=register[11];
    default: read_data2_reg=32'h00000000;
    endcase
     //
     end
    else
    begin
    register[0] = register[0];
    register[1] = register[1];
    register[2] = register[2];
    register[3] = register[3];
    register[4] = register[4];
    register[5] = register[5];
    register[6] = register[6];
    register[7] = register[7];
    register[8] = register[8];
    register[9] = register[9];
    register[10] = register[10];
    register[11] = register[11];

            case(read_reg1)
    5'b00000: read_data1_reg=register[0];
    5'b00001: read_data1_reg=register[1];
    5'b00010: read_data1_reg=register[2];
    5'b00011: read_data1_reg=register[3];
    5'b00100: read_data1_reg=register[4];
    5'b00101: read_data1_reg=register[5];
    5'b00110: read_data1_reg=register[6];
    5'b00111: read_data1_reg=register[7];
    5'b01000: read_data1_reg=register[8];
    5'b01001: read_data1_reg=register[9];
    5'b01010: read_data1_reg=register[10];
    5'b01011: read_data1_reg=register[11];
    default: read_data1_reg=32'h00000000;
    endcase

    case(read_reg2)
    5'b00000: read_data2_reg=register[0];
    5'b00001: read_data2_reg=register[1];
    5'b00010: read_data2_reg=register[2];
    5'b00011: read_data2_reg=register[3];
    5'b00100: read_data2_reg=register[4];
    5'b00101: read_data2_reg=register[5];
    5'b00110: read_data2_reg=register[6];
    5'b00111: read_data2_reg=register[7];
    5'b01000: read_data2_reg=register[8];
    5'b01001: read_data2_reg=register[9];
    5'b01010: read_data2_reg=register[10];
    5'b01011: read_data2_reg=register[11];
    default: read_data2_reg=32'h00000000;
    endcase
    end
  end



endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem, clk is not in your sensitivity list of the always block, but you use it in one of the if statements.

More concerning is the coding of this whole block. You are inferring latches when you want registers. The first thing to correct is that you are using blocking assignments "=" when you want non-blocking assignments "<=". The second thing that you should look into changing is pulling out the registers assignment and do that in a different always block. it will look something like this:

```
always@(posedge clk, posedge reset)
begin 
    if(reset)
        reset data
    else if( write_en0
        set regs to writedata
    else 
        reg <= reg 
end 

always@(posedge clk, posedge reset)
begin 
    read_data1 data
end 

always@(posedge clk, posedge reset)
begin 
    read_data2 data
end
```

this paper explains it well: 
http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs152/fa04/handouts/CummingsHDLCON1999_BehavioralDelays_Rev1_1.pdf

Comment: first is difference about <=, =